# Prevent a class from loading until a certain class is loaded

Tags: java, class, loading

The title says it all. I'm working on top of another project (aka working with Forge) and I want to put a certain class (class no. 1) on hold - not load it until another class (class no. 2) has been loaded. Then after that certain class (class no.2) has been loaded, the first class (class no. 1) should be normally loaded.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you feel that this is necessary, there is likely something very wrong with your software architecture.

Comment: @Philipp Im working on a Mod for Minecraft using Forge. What it does (if you know anything about it) is it loads the class for my creative tab before I initialize my blocks (aka put them in a SortedMap). Even though Forge itself is a great thing, some things are horribly handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your `Class1` when `Class2` gets loaded.

```
Class1 {
    public static void loadMe() {}
}
class2 {

    public Class2() {
        // Calling a dummy static member for loading the class
        Class1.loadMe();
    }
}
```

The advantage is that both will be loaded by the same ClassLoader by default. Alternatively, you can,

```
Class.forName("Class1");
```

In both the cases, no one in the entire App should try to access any static member of this class or it will get loaded.